# Measure window Non-Html Height?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way of measuring the Height of the selected section by Javascript / JQuery ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be an object called window.screen you can use to get the actual screen size and then you can subtract the availHeight from it to get height of the segment you are looking for. There is something about it here:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech3.shtml

Basically:

```
screen.height - screen.availHeight
```

and there is a bit more detail on W3Schools

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_screen.asp